# Identificar a coluna de referência de uma coluna virtual do Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, índices

Tenho um índice no Oracle em que uma das colunas é `DESC`. Crio ele da seguinte forma:

```
CREATE INDEX XFT25TB ON FT25T (FT07CODEMP, FI16MODELO, FT07CODIGO, FT25ORDIMP, DESC)
```

Porém, ao utilizar as views de dicionário de dados do Oracle, o índice referencia uma coluna virtual no lugar de referenciar a coluna `FT25ORDIMP`, conforme abaixo:

```
SELECT * FROM USER_IND_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'FT25T' AND INDEX_NAME = 'XFT25TB';

INDEX_NAME                     TABLE_NAME                     COLUMN_NAME                                                                      COLUMN_POSITION COLUMN_LENGTH CHAR_LENGTH DESCEND
------------------------------ ------------------------------ -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------- ------------- ----------- -------
XFT25TB                        FT25T                          FT07CODEMP                                                                                     1            22           0 ASC
XFT25TB                        FT25T                          FI16MODELO                                                                                     2             2           2 ASC
XFT25TB                        FT25T                          FT07CODIGO                                                                                     3            22           0 ASC
XFT25TB                        FT25T                          SYS_NC00006$                                                                                   4            34           0 DESC
```

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de obter o nome da coluna `FT25ORDIMP` a partir da coluna virtual `SYS_NC00006$`. Não encontrei nenhuma maneira de fazer essa referência diretamente.

Comment: https://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/check-for-column-expression-of-function-based-index-in-the-schema/ sem acesso ao Oracle para testar todavia

Comment: Não sabia que virtuais poderiam ser indexedas !

Comment: @Motta, no caso o que é indexado é uma coluna física mesmo, o próprio Oracle que cria a coluna virtual e insere no índice...

Comment: Outra questão também é que eu consigo ver, através da view `USER_IND_EXPRESSIONS`, a coluna física daquele item, no campo `COLUMN_EXPRESSION`, porém não consigo utilizar esse resultado em nenhum WHERE, obter como uma string nem nada, apenas visualizar...

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver criando uma função no banco, deixo aqui a quem puder interessar.

`CREATE OR replace FUNCTION COLUNAS_RAW_INDICES(p_tname IN VARCHAR2, p_cname IN VARCHAR2) 
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS 
  l_cursor   INTEGER DEFAULT DBMS_SQL.open_cursor; 
  l_n        NUMBER;
  l_long_val VARCHAR2(4000); 
  l_long_len NUMBER; 
  l_buflen   NUMBER := 4000; 
  l_curpos   NUMBER := 0; 
BEGIN 
    DBMS_SQL.PARSE(l_cursor, 'SELECT DATA_DEFAULT FROM USER_TAB_COLS WHERE '
                             || 'TABLE_NAME = :TableName '
                             || 'AND COLUMN_NAME = :ColumnName', DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
    DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN_LONG(l_cursor, 1); 
    DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE( l_cursor, ':TableName', p_tname);
    DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE( l_cursor, ':ColumnName', p_cname);
    l_n := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(l_cursor);
    IF (DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(l_cursor) > 0) THEN 
      DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE_LONG(l_cursor, 1, l_buflen, l_curpos, l_long_val, l_long_len); 
    END IF;
    DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(l_cursor); 
    RETURN RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(l_long_val, '"', ''))); 
END COLUNAS_RAW_INDICES;`

Dessa forma, executando o comando `SELECT COLUNAS_RAW_INDICES('FT25T', 'SYS_NC00006$') FROM DUAL` consigo obter como um `VARCHAR2` a coluna que eu preciso.